# Connection to local server through Flutter App works when using emulator, but not on any smartphone

Tags: python, flutter, dart, networking

I am working on establishing basic communication between two smartphones using a simple server. This server is designed to receive messages and forward them to all other devices that are waiting. The message transmission works perfectly when I use the app in the emulator on my PC (where the Python script is also running). However, there is no response when I try to connect to the server using the app on my smartphone. Additionally, I attempted to ping the server in the local network using the ConnectBot app, which worked without any issues. Yet, I am unable to establish a connection to the server through my app on the smartphone. Since I can't seem to run two emulators at the same time for some reason, I wanted to test the app using two smartphones, or one smartphone and the emulator.

My main.dart looks like this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Netzwerk-Kommunikations-App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController ipController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController portController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();
  Socket? socket;
  String clientType = 'sender';
  String receivedMessage = '';

  void showSnackbar(String message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  void connectToServer() async {
    try {
      socket = await Socket.connect(ipController.text, int.parse(portController.text));
      socket!.write(clientType);
      socket!.flush();
      showSnackbar('Verbindung zum Server erfolgreich');

      socket!.listen((data) {
        final serverResponse = String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
        if (serverResponse == 'Nachricht empfangen') {
          showSnackbar('Nachricht erfolgreich gesendet');
        } else {
          setState(() {
            receivedMessage = serverResponse;
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Fehler beim Verbinden zum Server: $e');
    }
  }

  void sendMessage() {
    if (socket != null && messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      socket!.write(messageController.text);
      socket!.flush();
      messageController.clear();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kommunikation Test'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(controller: ipController, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Server IP')),
            TextField(controller: portController, decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Port')),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    clientType = 'sender';
                    connectToServer();
                  },
                  child: Text('Als Sender verbinden'),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    clientType = 'receiver';
                    connectToServer();
                  },
                  child: Text('Als Empfänger verbinden'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            if (clientType == 'sender') ...[
              TextField(
                controller: messageController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nachricht'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: sendMessage,
                child: Text('Senden'),
              ),
            ],
            if (clientType == 'receiver') Text('Empfangene Nachricht: $receivedMessage'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the small python script looks like that:

```
import socket
import threading

def get_server_ip():
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
            s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
            return s.getsockname()[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Fehler beim Ermitteln der IP-Adresse: {e}")
        return "127.0.0.1"

def client_thread(conn, addr):
    try:
        client_type = conn.recv(1024).decode().strip()
        clients[client_type].append(conn)
        print(f"Neue Verbindung: {addr} als {client_type}")

        if client_type == 'sender':
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024).decode().strip()
                if not data:
                    break

                print(f"Nachricht von {addr}: {data}")

                for receiver in clients['receiver']:
                    receiver.sendall(data.encode())
                conn.sendall('Nachricht empfangen'.encode())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Fehler in der Verbindung {addr}: {e}")
    finally:
        conn.close()
        if client_type in clients:
            clients[client_type].remove(conn)

clients = {'sender': [], 'receiver': []}
server_ip = get_server_ip()
server_port = 12345

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((server_ip, server_port))
server.listen()

print(f"Server ist online auf {server_ip}:{server_port}")

try:
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=client_thread, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
finally:
    server.close()
```